# Electropus where did he/she come from?

Tags: discussion, electropus

[image: The Mighty Electropus]

Just wondering who made Electropus and if he/she has any particular license?

UPDATE: I spoke to Maddy from Little Bird electronics on the email and she thinks that the design originally came from [99designs.com](http://99designs.com) - So I might not find out who made this image in the first place. Maddy also informs me that the image was sold along with Chiphacker to the Stackexchange guys. I'll have to give them a nudge and see what they say.

Answer (score 2):

Electropus, IIRC, was created along with Chiphacker, the Stack Exchange v1.0 source of the current SE 2.0 site.  You'd want to talk to Madeleine or Marcus Schappi about that; if they didn't create it they'd likely (1) know who did and (2) hold any copyright on the image.

Neither [littlebirdceo](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/3/littlebirdceo) nor [mad_z](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/21/mad-z) have checked into the site recently, but you can still find them through the Little Bird Electronics about page:

http://littlebirdelectronics.com/pages/about-us

I don't want them to get spammed, so I won't list their phone number or email address here, but you can get it there.

Comment: nice one cheers :)